# Is it possible to use requests-cache functionalities on vercel?

Tags: django, sqlite, caching, python-requests, vercel

Since vercel doesn't support SQLite, I am wondering if python applications like Django deployed on vercel will be able to leverage the functionalities of python's popular requests-cache library.

Reason for this is because this library generate SQLite files for caching purpose.

Also, is there any workaround using SQLite on vercel.

What I tried: using requests-cache library for serverless environment.

What is expected: Django app running without any problem on vercel